# What is a reliable way to read binary data from a file, display the values as hex, and then save it?

Tags: c#, file, binary, hex, exe

I would like to read a binary file (say notepad.exe), and display a 2 character hex value for each binary value stored in the file. (a richtextbox should suffice)

Without making any changes, I wish to convert the hex back, and save it to a new file (just for demonstration), say - notepad2.exe , and have it work!!

The problem I have found is that there are so many ways to open the data stream to read the contents of a file, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get the raw (as stored on disk) data anymore without converting to some text format like Unicode, etc.

When downloading a file, the bytes are in a manageable fashion which I could easily convert to hex and display, but I am unable to find some form of 'readallbytes' for working with files already stored on the drive which can do this reliably. (and is likely why most hex editors appear to display correctly, but break the file when just opening and saving it back with no changes).

What is a reliable way to read all the raw bytes of a file, convert those bytes to hex for display, then convert the displayed hex back and save back to a file.

(I am aware of the articles on SO regarding converting binary to hex and back, which work for files you created with that method.  Thus far, they have proven unreliable when dealing with existing files (exe's, dll's etc).  They look like they work, aka, you can get hex values, but they are wrong as something gets lost in the conversion which ends up breaking the file you save back to disk.

Here is some sample code which will result in a non-functional copy of `notepad.exe` as `notepad2.exe`

```
// view hex
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes( Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows ), "notepad.exe"));
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace( BitConverter.ToString( data ).Replace( '-', ' ' ), "(.{"+72+"})", "$1"+"\n" );

// save hex back to file
data = richTextBox1.Text.Replace( "\n", "" ).Split( ' ' ).Select( b => Convert.ToByte( b, 16 ) ).ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes("notepad2.exe", data);
```

[image: copy looks good]

What is even more bizarre, is the copy doesn't run, yet FC shows this :

[image: fc result]

Even the [Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533) shows they are a match

[image: checksum verify]

... but it will not execute !  (double-clicking it doesn't appear to do anything - expected result in this demo would be to open notepad ! )

Comment: Umm....`byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");` First google result for "c# read all bytes".

Comment: @itsme86 - that was one of the things I tried. The problem I had is it does some sort of conversion for locale or whatever that alters the stream. So the bytes read, are not exactly the bytes on the disk.  Either that or there is a problem with the bin2hex and hex2bin conversions.  To be fair, I am not exactly sure where the problem lies, but something definitely goes haywire in between.  Working on a demo as we speak to add to the post.

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes()` doesn't do any kind of conversion, so there must be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps you're inadvertently manipulating the header bytes in your conversions... Need more details on what's breaking.

Comment: Added a functional (and simple) demonstration of this breaking the file when written back.  The result, is a `notepad2.exe` file, that looks right, but does not run.

Comment: Can you compute a checksum, such as SHA1 or even MD5, on both input and output and report whether the file contents are the same or different?  There are a lot of things that can cause a program not to execute that aren't simply "wrong file content".

Comment: @BenVoigt will try that now. (using this tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11533 , and will add the hash results to the question)

Comment: Do you have an antivirus scanner running?

Comment: @MatthewWhited no.  Dev machine doesn't communicate with the web so it's clean, no AV, or any 3rd party stuff to interfere with the process.

Comment: It's something with notepad.exe.  It will not execute if I even copy it to the local folder with `File.Copy(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "notepad.exe"), "notepad_copy.exe");`

Comment: You can not even run notepad if you copy it from the commandline to another folder.  It must be part of windows security.

Comment: @MatthewWhited - ok.  thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll let you add all the error handling.

```
string ReadFileAsHexString(string filename)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    return bytes.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                           (sb, v) => sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2} ", v))
                .ToString();
}

void WriteHexStringAsBinaryToFile(string hex, string filename)
{
    var bytes = hex.Split(new [] {' '},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16))
                   .ToArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I have been doing, although I am not using StringBuilder, I am using BitConverter.

Comment: that should work too except you will need to replace the split on space with split on dash.

Comment: Exactly.  Sorry was a bit late in adding a code example, was a problem I recalled having that I felt needed addressing on SO and wanted to out it before I forgot.  The sample of what I am doing above with compares and file checks. Still, with no modification to the hex data, the resulting exe won't run and I don't understand why - when everything shows they are identical lol.  Upvoting you since you took the time to reply, and I don't feel your method (or mine) is wrong.  The problem of a 'broken' exe still remains tho.